# CentOS7 on VMware: How to reach Docker service from Host

Tags: centos, vmware, port-forwarding, docker

I want to access the guests docker services via browser with IP:port/service. For example, I'm running a RabbitMQ, which I want to check.

Unfortunately I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, when trying to access the guest from the host. My network is using a proxy, so I added the guests (and so the hosts) IP to the "not using proxy" list.

I have docker installed on a CentOS 7, which runs several services and which are also mapped in docker:

```
docker ps
PORTS
0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp, 4369/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp (rabbitMQ)
```

CentOS itself runs in a VMWare player with NAT network settings, so it uses the host IP address (IPv4). The bridge of docker is enabled.

The firewall is disabled:

```
firewall-cmd --state
not running
```

What am I missing and what can I do to access the docker services?
If some information are missing, then let me know - I will add it immediately.
TIA.

Comment: Did you [port forward](https://hitchhikingtheweb.wordpress.com/2014/09/02/portforwarding-with-vmware-player-and-nat/) guest port in VMWare Player?

Comment: For what reason? I just want to access the guest machine, which is located on the host. There should be no other access from outside my host-machine.